# Custom 404 action in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rescue

Default Rails will render 404.html, then it thinks an error 404 is appropriate. However, I want make it by custom page. Please suggest the proper way do it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use [render_404 monkey patching.](http://henrik.nyh.se/2008/07/rails-404)

Or, you could set a default route at the bottom of your routes file that goes to an action that returns a 404 status code.

Ideally if you do not want any custom code in your 404 you can just edit the static 404.html, which is easiest.

Comment: There is a broken link.

Answer (score 4):

This answer was surprisingly hard to find.

If you want a static page, edit `404.html`. Done.

If you want a dynamic page, then:

in config/routes.rb:

```
match '*not_found', to: 'errors#error_404' unless Rails.application.config.consider_all_requests_local
```

Comment out the `unless` clause to test the 404 page on local dev machine.

Generate a bunch of files:

```
rails generate controller errors error_404
```

Edit `views/errors/error_404.html.erb` to customize.

This works for Rails 3.1 and 3.2.2.

Comment: what about the code for dynamic error pages for other status codes like 500 or 422?

Comment: Great solution!  So much simpler than the other answers I found around this issue.  Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on what you need, our gem might help:  http://github.com/hedgeyedev/snow